# Does pressure in a closed container increase or decrease with increase in acceleration of the container?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, pressure, acceleration

Let there be some air contained in a vessel whose walls are elastic. The vessel is closed and we impart some velocity to it. Please note that the gas inside the container is stationary w.r.t. the container. But the container, itself, is moving with some acceleration. The gas particles should  press against the walls in a direction opposite to the direction of motion.

My question is can we say whether the internal pressure created by the gas particles increase or decrease with increase in the acceleration of the vessel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The inertia of the gas will force some of the gas towards the 'back' of the container, assuming the container accelerates 'forwards.' So the 'front' of the container will have a lower pressure and the 'back' will have a higher pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration creates a pressure *gradient* within the container. If the container were perfectly rigid, then the pressure would decrease at the "front" (where the wall is accelerating away from the gas molecules) and it would increase at the "back" (where the wall is accelerating toward the gas.)

But you said,

> Since the walls are elastic, wouldn't...?

If you are asking about how the container will be [*strained*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(physics)) by the accelerating force, then the experiment gets more complicated than I know how to describe. It's going to depend on the geometry of the container, on its material properties, and on where the accelerating force is applied. Just for example, imagine how it could depend on whether it's being accelerated by a force that is pulling on the "front" end, vs. by a force that is pushing on the "back."

Comment: Since the walls are elastic, wouldn't the particles exert pressure to extend the walls, leading to overall drop in the internal pressure?

Comment: @user146290, see my edited answer. I'll probably have to delete it soon because I don't know how to answer questions about stress and strain.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the equivalence principle. As Solomon Slow said, the pressure will be higher at the rear of the container relative to the direction of acceleration. Just as in a column of air on earth the pressure is higher at the bottom of the column than at the top. The same column of gas on Jupiter would have a correspondingly higher pressure lapse rate with altitude. i.e., Higher acceleration would produce a larger pressure difference between front and rear.